# Is it possible to run filter2D (convolution) at just one point in an image?

Tags: opencv

I am currently running [`filter2D`](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/filtering.html#filter2d) to convolute a kernel with an image:

```
cv::filter2D(source, 
             dest, 
             CV_64F, 
             kernal, 
             cv::Point(-1,-1), 
             0, 
             cv::BORDER_CONSTANT);
```

However, I am not interested in convoluting the whole image with a kernel, I just want to run the convolution at a given pixel on the source image.

Is this possible?

Comment: Just seen a note from the documentation which suggests this will just work by cropping a 1px ROI - > Note When the source image is a part (ROI) of a bigger image, the function will try to use the pixels outside of the ROI to form a border. To disable this feature and always do extrapolation, as if src was not a ROI, use borderType | BORDER_ISOLATED. http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/filtering.html

Comment: That sounds reasonable, though you could probably also do it manually doing something like `filterVal = subM.mul(kernel).sum;` where `subM` is the ROI.

Comment: @beaker - Cool, thanks - I didn't know you could do that.  What would happen to the pixels border using that method?

Comment: If `subM` is wholly contained within your original matrix (i.e., all values exist) they will all be used. If `subM` falls off the edge of your image, you would have to manually fill in with the desired values. For instance, if you wanted to use a 3x3 kernel on pixel `(0,0)` of the image, you'd have to pad the ROI with the 5 missing values from row -1 and column -1 using something like [copyMakeBorder](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/filtering.html?highlight=copymakeborder#copymakeborder).

Answer (score 3):

The answer was simple, from the documentation[enter link description here](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/filtering.html):

> Note When the source image is a part (ROI) of a bigger image, the function will try to use the pixels outside of the ROI to form a border

So the solution is:

```
cv::Point point(x, y); 
Mat onePixelSourceROI(source, cv::Rect( point, cv::Size(1, 1) ));

cv::filter2D(onePixelSourceROI, 
             dest, 
             CV_64F, 
             kernal, 
             cv::Point(-1,-1), 
             0, 
             cv::BORDER_CONSTANT);
```